# Port details of running process

Tags: node.js, linux, shell

Is is possible for a running node process on a server to make a query(to be written in the node process code) to know the port it's running on without external intervention ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question I think you are looking for this:

https://github.com/yibn2008/find-process